# .start() does not result in starting the thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I am learning multithreading in python. I created the below example but the .start() never started the thread.
please let me know how to fix thid error

**code**:

```
import threading
import time
import logging

class ThreadsSync:

def __new__(cls):
    """
    this will be invoked once the creation procedure of the object begins
    """
    instance = super(ThreadsSync,cls).__new__(cls)
    return instance

def __init__(self):
    """
    this will be invoked once the initialisation procedure of the object begins
    """
    self.configLogging()
    self.spawnThreads()

def configLogging(self):
    format = "%(asctime)s: %(message)s"
    logging.basicConfig(format=format, level=logging.INFO,datefmt="%H:%M:%S")
    logging.getLogger().setLevel("DEBUG")

def spawnThreads(self):
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        thread1 = threading.Thread(target=backgroundTask,args=(10,))
        #thread2 = threading.Thread(target=backgroundTask, args=(20,))
        thread1.start()
        #thread2.start()

def backgroundTask(threadName,numOfLoops):
    for i in numOfLoops:
        print(threadName, "-"*22, time.time())
```

Comment: How do you start the script, maybe you are not in the __main__ module?

Comment: @eckes i just press ctrl + f5

Answer (score 0):

There were a few issues

1. The indenting in the post seems incorrect
2. `if __name__ == "__main__":` doesn't seem like it's in the right place, deleted
3. class is never called: added call at bottom
4. changed `Thread` input to `target=self.backgroundTask`
5. changed `numOfLoops` to `range(numOfLoops)`

```py
import threading
import time
import logging

class ThreadsSync:

    def __new__(cls):
        """
        this will be invoked once the creation procedure of the object begins
        """
        instance = super(ThreadsSync,cls).__new__(cls)
        return instance

    def __init__(self):
        """
        this will be invoked once the initialisation procedure of the object begins
        """
        self.configLogging()
        self.spawnThreads()

    def configLogging(self):
        format = "%(asctime)s: %(message)s"
        logging.basicConfig(format=format, level=logging.INFO,datefmt="%H:%M:%S")
        logging.getLogger().setLevel("DEBUG")

    def spawnThreads(self):
        thread1 = threading.Thread(target=self.backgroundTask,args=(10,))
        #thread2 = threading.Thread(target=backgroundTask, args=(20,))
        thread1.start()
        #thread2.start()

    def backgroundTask(threadName,numOfLoops):
        for i in range(numOfLoops):
            print(threadName, "-"*22, time.time())
if __name__==‘__main__’:
    ThreadsSync()
```

Comment: please tell me why i can not use if __name__ == __main__??also the way you provided does not solve the problem

Comment: `if __name__=__main__` is used to execute code when the script is called directly (code under this is not executed when script is imported etc). I don’t see the point of using it there. You can use it at bottom (see updated solution when you call to start the threads. My solution starts the thread like you asked. What other problem do you want to solve?